# Error using Animation package R

Tags: r, imagemagick

Tried to run the following code in R:

```
ani.options(
   convert = shQuote("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16/convert.exe")
)
 saveGIF(
{
  for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10), ylim = 0:1)
},
 movie.name = "test.gif", 
interval = 0.2, 
ani.width = 300, 
ani.height = 300,
outdir = getwd()
)
```

Getting the error message:

```
Executing: 
"\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0 -delay 20     Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png
Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "test.gif"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
[1] FALSE
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "\"C:/Program     Files/ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16/convert.exe\"" --version' had status 1 
2: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "test.gif"' had status 1 
3: In cmd.fun(convert) :
  '"\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "test.gif"' execution failed with error code 1
4: running command '"\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png     Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png "test.gif"' had status 127
```

Could someone please point on my mistake.

Comment: don't forget `print`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it seems it is due to the path to convert.
If I type:

> ani.options(convert = shQuote('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/convert.exe'))

And then check the path

> ani.options("convert")
>   [1] "\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/convert.exe\""

However, if I do:

> ani.options(convert = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/convert.exe')
>   ani.options("convert")
>   [1] "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/convert.exe"

It is the correct path and saveGIF works.... weird things...